# insert data to nonlinked server using SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have two sql 2008 R2 servers, which are not linked. I need to read data from server A and write them to server B. Best way is to use SSIS.
But the data insert has to be generic, that means, I do not know the table structure. I have sql queries ready (when I run them on linked server, it works), but SSIS with oledb source and oledb destination needs table structure to do the column mapping.
how can I run dynamic sql task using SSIS and be able to read data from server A and insert them to server B (and then perform rollback on error)?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is probably BiML, which dynamically creates SSIS packages based on meta data.